# Creating new table for related data in database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, rdbms

I have a SQL table `Users`, with each user having multiple educational institutions. E.g. John may have gone to Harvard in 2019, Oxford in 2020 and Cambridge in 2021.

Since this is a one to many relationship the most obvious solution would be to create a second table - `UserEducation` which references userID.

However, I feel a bit wrong about this approach as a user's educational institutions are directly a part of their profile rather than a new set of data. Is there any other way to do this (which somehow keeps the idea of separate entries for each user profile) or is the way I am doing it fine?

Comment: Look for ManyToMany relationship, you may want a table that holds the schools a table that holds the Users and a last table that holds the relationship between them. A single user can have had many schools and a single schools can have had many users

Comment: I had considered that but I do not really want to hold data about schools as that way I would have to basically hold all the schools in the world

Comment: Then, a OneToMany is the way to go, you're on the good track

Comment: i think UserEducation is totally fine. You can hold education data as json/xml inside user table, but personally i wouldnt want to deal with it like this

Comment: Alright, UserEducation seems like the right choice, thank you.

Comment: *Since this is a one to many relationship* - ??? If *John may have gone to Harvard in 2019* then nobody else may have gone to Harvard in 2019 too? I doubt... Many-to-Many.

Answer (score 0):

I vote for 1:many -- 1 user to many institutions.  I vote against many-to-many because of the year being involved.

The 1:many table would look like:

John may have gone to Harvard in 2019, Oxford in 2020 and Cambridge in 2021.

```
John   Harvard   2019
John   Oxford    2020
John   Cambridge 2021
Leslie Cambridge 2019
```

"John" would probably be an "id" for `JOINing` to the `Persons` table, where you have one row for John and one for Leslie.

You may do likewise for `Harvard` and a different `id` -- if you have more information about the schools.  (If there is no further info, don't bother.)

If you don't need to search or sort or Join on school, the Ali's suggestion of a JSON column with all the schools for each user, in the `Persons` table, would work fine.